# split a value from Xml Data content and adding in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Title>
   <subtitle>12,15,1,4 </subtitle>
 </Title >
```

This is my `xml structure` and I need to split the value and add it to `dropdownlist`, but I'm getting whole value in `dropdownlist`, kindly provide me the solution and my code is

```
private void bindxml()
{
    StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filepath);
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        ds.ReadXml(filepath);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "subtitle";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: get that value in string variable and split that string by comma (,) and separate out each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(XElement.Load(filepath).Element("subtitle").Value
    .Split(',').Select(x => new ListItem(x)).ToArray());
```

Load the XML, navigate to the "`subtitle`" element, split that value using the comma delimiter and then create a new ListItem for each element. Pass this collection, as an array, to the `DropDownList` `AddRange` method.

Comment: thank you,Answer works and minimise the code in single line instead of 20 lines.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
string elements = string.Empty;
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string xmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml");  //File Name
xml.Load(xmlFilePath);

XmlNodeList companyList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("subtitle");

foreach (XmlNode node in companyList)
{
    XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)node;

    elements = companyElement.InnerText; 
}

List<int> subIds = new List<int>();
if (elements!="")
{
    subIds = elements.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();    
}

ddlSub.DataSource = TagIds;
ddlSub.DataBind();
ddlSub.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Subtitle--", "0"));
```